# Paste copied cells into offset cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a monthly report that copies cell values and pastes them onto specific rows depending on some simple criteria.
[Pre Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Luxk.png)

I already have a IF function that =1 if my conditions are met. This is located in column C.

My goal is to copy 5 cells and simply paste-values them in the row that the filter = 1.

The following VBA has been myself playing with the option to filter to only show that specific row that =1, and then selection the 'Criteria 1', to paste in the first visible row below
[Post Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQIHo.png)

```
Sub Macro11()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'
Dim PasteCell As Range
Set PasteCell = Range("F2").Offset(1, 0).Value 'F2 is the header for Criteria 1'

'Copy values from plan
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MonthlyDump").Range("N1:R1").Select
    Selection.Copy
'Filter to only show the IF function = 1, plus blanks so the headings still show
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$J$64").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="1", _
    Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
'Click on header, then pastes into first visible cell on the row below (the filtered row)
    PasteCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Clear filters
    ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$J$64").AutoFilter Field:=1
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

It currently fails on the first line 'Dim PasteCell As range', 424 object required.

But I am wondering if this is the best way to even go about this, **ideally** I would just like to look down column C until C65, and if it sees a 1, then pastes-values 3 cells to the right.

Is anyone able to come it with an elegant solution to this? My second option would be preferred as this seems the quickest way to a solution without requiring manually filtering.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This doesn't look like the most suitable method. Please try the code below instead.

```
Sub Macro11()
    ' 204
    
    Dim Arr     As Variant          ' temorary array
    Dim Rng     As Range            ' temporary range
    Dim Rt      As Variant          ' Row: target

    Arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MonthlyDump").Range("N1:R1").Value
    With ActiveSheet                'better to name the sheet (!)
        ' start lookin in row 3
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(64, "C"))
        ' same as above but last row is dynamic:-
        ' Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        
        Rt = Application.Match(1, Rng, 0)
        If IsError(Rt) Then
            MsgBox "No row matches the criteria.", _
                   vbExclamation, "Failed to post"
        Else
            .Cells(Rt + Rng.Row - 1, "D").Resize(1, UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This code uses the MATCH function to find the first 1 in column C. Actually, this looks like not being the optimum, either. It should be possible to look for the conditions that you use to set column C to 1 and 0, perhaps a date. If the code would look for the date, or whatever other criterium, instead of the 1 column C wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Variatus, this is excellent mate! I just had to alter the  Else
            .Cells(Rt + Rng.Row - 1, "D").Resize(1, UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
        End If to "F" to get the correct row but this is spot on mate